# setuid (and other) permissions lost when copying / elsewhere - what to do?

Tags: permissions, system-installation, setuid, corruption

I sort-of-cloned an existing Debian 7.x distro by copying the contents of the root filesystem (not the special dirs of course) to another HDD. I booted, things seem to run, but - I get some weird errors. One of them - sudo and su wouldn't run, complaining about lack of a setuid permission for the binaries. Well, I fixed that, and now they don't complain, but - maybe there are other files whose permission has been screwed up during the copy? Is there someway to verify and fix all relevant file permissions?

Comment: What command did you use to do the copy?

Comment: Just `cp`, unfortunately...

Comment: What options? Just `-r` or `-R`?

Comment: It was just `cp -r` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original host (or another similar freshly installed distro):

```
getfacl -R / > permissions.acl
```

your host:

```
setfacl --restore=permissions.acl
```

from [here](http://linuxconfig.org/backup-permissions-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

That's what God made `rsync` for.

I clone my installs using `rsync -avxt --delete-before`, then I run `lilo` on them to make them independently bootable. Yeah, have to make sure your `fstab` doesn't use UUIDs though, or everything goes to hell. I use labels so that it doesn't matter what the disk order (`sda`, `sdb`, etc.) is.

Comment: Why is the `--delete-before` switch important?

Comment: When you are cloning, you want (usually!) to not only add new files, but remove old ones as well. '--delete-before' cleverly does that before adding any new files, so that if you have limited space, you are sure not to run out (which might happen if it added all the new files before removing any of the old ones). Oh, you might want to add the '-t' switch as well to preserve your files' modification times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way I can think of. One way would be to reinstall each and every package you have in `/var/cache/apt/archives` as root (`sudo su`).

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
for i in *.deb
do
sudo dpkg -Gi $i
done
```

Next time, use the `-p` option of rsync/cp or equivalent of whatever you were using to copy the files.

Comment: How about "copying" the permissions and owners from the original partition, without the files? or "syncing" the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Use tar to archive the files and then extract them. You p key when extract to keep original partitions

Comment: I'm talking about a copy which already happened.

Comment: So create two lists, based on permissions and filename/directory name and compare them. Here is how to create such list: ls -l|awk '{print $1" "$NF}'

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsync` to re-copy the files. I think it will notice that only the permissions need to be copied, so it will fix them up while leaving the contents alone, so it should be relatively quick.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference you can use

> `cp --preserve`
>
> preserve the specified attributes (default: mode, ownership, timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all

to copy a file and preserve permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The `--attributes-only`  option of `cp` will allow you
to fix your broken copy.

```
cp --attributes-only -p file1 file2
```

will set the attributes of *`file2`* to match those of *`file1`.* 
This copies the mode (including sticky and set*X*ID bits),
owner, mtime and atime. 
It may also be able to copy ACLs, security context
and/or extended attributes.
To copy anything other than the default list,
specify the ones you want to copy with `--preserve=list`
where *`list`* is a comma-separated list of `mode`, `ownership`,
`timestamps`, `context`, `links`, and `xattr`; or `all`. 
See [cp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html). 
(I don’t know what `links` means.)

The contents of *`file2`* are not modified. 
(If *`file2`* does not exist,
an empty file will be created with the attributes of *`file1`*.)

Naturally, this will fail
if you aren’t superuser or otherwise sufficiently privileged.

So you can do

```
cp --attributes-only --preserve=all -r dir1/. dir2
```

where *`dir1`* is your old, clean, reference disk
and *`dir2`* is your new, mangled copy.

As far as I can tell, this doesn’t offer any way of checking attributes
without fixing them, or even of reporting what changes it makes.

Comment: I’m astonished that nobody else has posted this!